# require any php file with function generate 500 internal server error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with    require_once './DBFunctions.php'; rather server generate this error once I require any file with function even before call that function, btw my code is working correctly locally (i.e., this error only when I test scripts on server) .

My question is there any error with ***function*** keyword in **php version 5.2.5** ?(I use mysql library instead of mysqli cause it's not supported on my server ).

This is my code ,

index.php

```
<?php  require_once "./DBfun.php" ?>
<!-- html goes here -->
```

DBfun.php

```
 <?php require_once './DBConfig.php';

 function sanitize(&$data) {
return htmlentities(strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($data)));}

function isExist($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
   $query = "SELECT * FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERNAME` ='$username' AND `STATUS`=1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row_cnt = mysql_num_rows($result);
$r = ($row_cnt == 1) ? "1 row matched (User Exist)" : " No matched found (User does 't      exist)";
$log = "Query: " . $query . PHP_EOL . "Result: " . $r . PHP_EOL;
//file_put_contents(LOG_FILE, $log, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
// destruct($result);
return ($row_cnt == 1) ? TRUE : FALSE;}
 ?>
```

I tested everything DB connection, queries (retrive data & display it), ajax requests, require files even nested requires etc.. without functions, & it worked for me, the error appear when I use (uncomment) any function =(

The error I get :

```
 GET http://192.168.0.36/ProjectName/index.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: 500 errors should show up in your web server **error log** (not the access log). That will tell you what went wrong

Comment: I've just checked it, it's empty bro

Comment: @m.hyari Make sure you have error logging on your web server as well as in your PHP config file is turned on. You can view the active PHP config file using `phpinfo();`

Comment: check whether exist these functions. Duplicates make fatal error. http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php

Comment: as I tell the code is working correctly locally so there is no any of these errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the file exists before you require .. however i'm sure this is not the problem.

```
<?php

    $file = './path/to/file.php';

    if (is_file($file))
    {
        require_once($file);
    }

?>
```

Comment: the `require_once` work correctly . I tried to echo some data without functions , further more a data from DB & it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for help 
The Problem was in the version of php on the Server 
Where pre-defined function `array_map` which I used in my script